# Are there simple rings that are not division rings but have no zero divisors?

Tags: ring-theory

The only examples of simple rings I know that are not division rings a matrices over simple rings, but matrix rings always have zero divisors.

Are there simple rings that are not division rings but have no zero divisors?
Else is having no zero divisors a sufficient condition for simple rings to be division rings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Weyl algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_algebra) $\mathbb C[x,\partial_x]$ is an example of such a ring.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a simpler example? I haven't studied Weyl algebras

Comment: @ArunKumar This is the standard example for a simple domain. Looks like you've got an excuse now to learn about it :)